# Getting `502 Bad Gateway` when sending request with Guzzle PHP

Tags: laravel, nginx, guzzle

I am having an App developed on Laravel 5.4. I used to have my project setup on Xampp on Windows and also under vagrant Machine.

The problem is that when I switched to MacOS and Valet, I have started getting problems with routes that were sending requests via Guzzlehttp package.

They imideatelly responded with `502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.13.10`, though I could access the same endpoints on 3rd party domains directly and even though I wrapped the code with exception handler.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski I dont' have problems with Homestead. As I said - the project works fine on Homestead and with Windows Xampp. It has problems with Laravel Valet

Comment: Is it possible Valet isn't working correctly? Do you see other sites normally that you are running with Valet? If they are also getting a 502, note that you may need to run ```valet install``` after Valet is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem of 502 Bad Gateway using Guzzle. I fixed it by removing User-Agent from request.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.example.com', [
headers' => ['User-Agent' => null]
]);
```